# kubectl run command creates mulitple pods instead of one

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I am learning kubernetes ing GCP. I was trying out steps given in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSYxW_c3M_E&list=PLTyWtrsGknYfanKF33E12LdJvl5q5PZGp&index=4).While doing deployment to cluster , we are doing

```
kubectl run gcp-spring-app --image=gcr.io/secondproject-275119/gcp-app-image --port=9080
```

which gives below error

```
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
deployment.apps/gcp-spring-app created
```

Upon searching the error i got that we should use `--generator=run-pod/v1` and command look like this now

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 gcp-spring-app --image=gcr.io/secondproject-275119/gcp-app-image --port=9080
```

It is actually working , but now when I do `kubectl get pods`, I am seeing multiple pods instead of one.Like below

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
gcp-spring-app                    1/1     Running   0          36s
gcp-spring-app-67767bd649-jvg9h   1/1     Running   0          4m55s
```

Can anybody explain why these two got created as I need one also if I should tweak the command to get only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pod gcp-spring-app-67767bd649-jvg9h is from your first invocation of the command. (Look at the 'age')
The second pod is from your second invocation.

Actually the deprecation notice does not prevent the execution, creating a job, which then creates the pod with the random suffix.

Comment: understood, one more question, now I want to delete that unwanted pods, kubectl delete pods gcp-spring-app-67767bd649-jvg9h when doing this instantly a new pods is coming up..any heads up

Comment: The first invocation created a job, the job is responsible that the pod is always existing (one of the benefits of kubernetes is to be able to create new pods for failed ones). So just delete the job: `kubectl delete job gcp-spring-app`